# In which terminal do I run these commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, buildpack

I'm trying to create a buildpack with [libwebp](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/), and I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/blog/create-first-heroku-buildpack/), which starts with the following commands:

1. `heroku create buildpack-stager`
2. `heroku run bash --app buildpack-stager`
3. `curl -O https://mupdf.googlecode.com/files/mupdf-1.3-source.tar.gz`
4. `tar -xvzf mupdf-1.3-source.tar.gz`
5. ...

Should these initial commands be run in the terminal of my application on heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heroku create` should be run on your local machine. This [creates a new app on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps-create-app), so if you already have an app to work with it may not be necessary.

`heroku run bash` should also be run on your local machine. This [spins up a one-off dyno for your app and runs the command `bash` on it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno).

From there, it looks like they want you to continue with `curl`, `tar`, etc. in the same shell as the previous step. The effect will be that these commands are run on the one-off dyno you're using, but you don't need to change terminals or anything.

You might find the [Heroku CLI commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands) documentation page helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All these commands you should run on your local terminal (bash, etc.)